# Iterate over NULL terminated array of strings using for_each

Tags: c++

Iterating over a NULL terminated string using for_each is possible:

```
const char *name = "Bob";

void func(const char &arg)
{
   cout << arg;
}

int main()
{
    for_each(name, name + strlen(name), func);
}
```

Is something similar possible for a NULL terminated list of strings (without having to determine the total length of the list first) such as:

```
const char *names[] = { "Bob", "Adam", "Simon", NULL };
```

Comment: In C++ a list of strings should be represented using `std::list<std::string>` (or `std::vector` if that suits better). This would solve all your problems at once.

Comment: In what way similar? You _are_ determining the length of your string in your example.

Comment: @eq- I realise I am determining the length of the string in my example, but I would prefer not to. Also when there is a single string determining the length is trivial, but with a large array of strings it becomes more tedious. I really want something I can pass in as the end iterator that will cause the ending NULL in the array to be detected as the end of the list by for_each automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

std::for_each "iterates" over a range, so to use it with an array of indeterminate length, you need to use custom iterators to signal the end of the array (on NULL member). If you insist on using NULL-terminated char* array, you could of course create your own for_each function for it, for example like this:

```
template <typename Function>
void for_each_in_null_terminated_cstring_array(const char** array, Function f)
{
    while (*array) {
        f(*array);
        array++;
    }
}

const char *names[] = { "Bob", "Adam", "Simon", NULL };
for_each_in_null_terminated_cstring_array(names, func);
```

I'm not really recommending this solution, though.

edit: Yes, more general is always *more* better, isn't it?

```
template <typename T, typename Function>
void for_each_in_null_terminated_array(T* array, Function f)
{
    while (*array) {
        f(*array);
        array++;
    }
}
```

---

(Here's the implementation of a null terminated ("false"-terminated) iterator I mentioned earlier - with a change or two based on suggestions below. It should be a real InputIterator)

```
template <class T>
class nt_iterator: public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T>
{
public:
    typedef typename nt_iterator<T>::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename nt_iterator<T>::value_type value_type;

    nt_iterator(): p(), pte(true) {}
    nt_iterator(pointer p_): p(p_), pte(!p_) {}
    nt_iterator(const nt_iterator<T>& rhs): p(rhs.p), pte(rhs.pte) {}
    nt_iterator<T>& operator++() {
        ++p;
        if (!*p) pte = true; // once past-the-end, always past-the-end
        return *this;
    }
    nt_iterator<T> operator++(int) {
        nt_iterator n(*this);
        operator++();
        return n;
    }
    bool operator==(const nt_iterator<T>& rhs) {
        return pte && rhs.pte || p == rhs.p;
    }
    bool operator!=(const nt_iterator<T>& rhs) {
        return !(operator==(rhs));
    }
    value_type operator*() { return *p; }

private:
    pointer p;
    bool pte; // past-the-end flag
};
```

And how it's used:

```
void print(const char* str);

int main()
{
    const char* array[] = {"One", "Two", "Three", NULL, "Will you see this?"};
    std::for_each(nt_iterator<const char*>(array),
                  nt_iterator<const char*>(),
                  print);
}
```

It's probably a bit slower than the loop version, because of the increased amount of equivalence checks - the speed difference is of course insignificant compared to, for example, printing text - but one should note that `std::for_each` does *not* magically make looping faster (in fact, you might be surprised to see how your compiler vendor defines the function - that is, if you are expecting too much).

Comment: No, you don't need to determine the length *by definition*. This is possible with custom iterators. It'd be ugly, but it can be done.

Comment: Still, +1 as I recommend this solution.

Comment: This is quite handy! Small critiques: I would say that you oughtn't to use `== NULL` and should rely on either `operator!` or `== T()`, e.g., `pte = !*p;`. Also, the usual way of specifying a generic past-the-end iterator is with the default constructor, as for example `std::istream_iterator`.

Comment: (I re-added the code I pulled because it seemed unnecessary) I agree - I've kind of mixed NULL's and negations here and there. I actually first used `pte = !*p` but I was thinking all pointers and thought it seemed too tricky - it'd be the version I'd use in my own code, tho ;)

Comment: Looks great to me. I'll definitely use something like this if I ever run across a case for it.

Comment: Did you lose a `*` in the initialization of `pte`?  Shouldn't it be `pte(!*p_)`?  In the example, `T` is a `const char *`, so `pointer` would be `const char * *`, right?

Answer (score 3):

With

```
const char *names[] = { "Bob", "Adam", "Simon" };
```

you can just call

```
std::for_each(names, names + sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]), func );
```

or, nicer, using [two helper functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552839/which-c-standard-library-wrapper-functions-do-you-use/2553081#2553081):

```
std::for_each(begin(names), end(names), func );
```

Of course, this fails the moment the array decays into a pointer (but at least the compiler won't accept it then). If you *must* rely on that trailing `NULL`, you either need to write your own looping function or count before-hand, as with `std::strlen()`:

```
std::ptr_diff_t num = std::find( names
                               , names + std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()
                               , NULL);
std::for_Each( names, names+num, func );
```

Comment: And with the NULL terminated array of strings this technique works if you substract one from the end pointer - "names + sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]) - 1".

Comment: @Andrew: Either that or make `func()` capable of dealing with `NULL` arguments.

Comment: I am referring to the OP's requirement "without having to determine the total length of the list first". You're using `sizeof` to do just that.

Comment: @larsmans You are correct - I would prefer a solution with having to find the length of the list first.

Comment: @Andrew: Then you should pick [eq's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033071/iterate-over-null-terminated-array-of-strings-using-for-each/4033248#4033248). It's good and I up-voted it.

Comment: @larsmans: Ah, I see. I read this as "i don't want to have to iterate over all the items twice". My fault.

Comment: @sbi - I meant to say "without having to find the length first" - oops.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Basilevs answer with a fully working solution.

A custom iterator may be defined as follows:

```
template <class T>
class NullTerminatedIterator
    :public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,
    T,ptrdiff_t,const T*,const T&>
{
public:
    typedef NullTerminatedIterator<T> NTI;

    NullTerminatedIterator(T * start): current(start) {}
    NTI & operator++() {current++; return *this;}
    T & operator*() { return *current; } 
    static NTI end() { return NTI(0); }
    bool operator==(const NTI & that) { return *current == *that.current; }
    bool operator!=(const NTI & that) { return *current != *that.current; }
private:
    T * current;
};
```

And then used like so:

```
const char *names[] = {"Bob", "Adam", "Simon", NULL};

NullTerminatedIterator<char*> iter((char**)names);

for_each(iter, NullTerminatedIterator<char*>::end(), func);
```

The base class for the NullTerminatedIterator are taken from this [custom iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839958/custom-iterator-in-c/840055#840055) question.

This only traverses the list during the for_each call, as requested.

Comment: @Basilevs - Are you referring to the static function or the static const variable nullNTI? This code runs correctly in VS2010.

Comment: @Basilevs - Maybe it was just the cast of 0 to (T*) that I needed, but it wouldn't compile in VS2010 when trying to initialise with NTI(0).

Comment: @Basilevs - Turns out the NTI(0) not working was just a consequence of something else not compiling at the time - fixed in answer now, along with correct use of NullTerminatedIterator in for_each line. Thanks again!

Comment: Damn, I've just noticed you are an OP :)

Answer (score 1):

There have been multiple answers that tell you what you can do instead. However the answer to your particular question is just "no, you can't" :)

Comment: @sbi: nah... that still iterates over the sequence two times, I think what the OP wants is that the range be iterated once. But with for_each. I believe it's impossible

Comment: Yes, he can. See my reply to eq-'s answer.

Comment: @larsmans: you mean like create an iterator and  iter1 == iter2 if and only if *iter1 == null?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible. You just need to write an iterator type in which the end iterator is "special" and doesn't point to a specific location, but instead just compares equal to any iterator that points to a null value. It's kind of similar to the stream iterators already in the standard library.

Comment: @larsmans, @jalf: Yeah, I guess. But it's not worth it, is it? Whatever, my answer is wrong, I'll delete it soon

Comment: @Armen: I never said it was worth it. Just that it is possible ;) (It's also one of the stronger arguments in favor of Alexandrescu's "iterators must go" thing. Something like this would be much more natural to express as a range.)

Comment: @jalf: I would love to see a solution that used some kind of custom iterator to allow the standard for_each to be used efficiently.

Comment: @Andrew: Well, write one. ;) If you use Boost's Iterator library to do the heavy lifting, it's not that much work. I've done something similar before. :)

Comment: @jalf: I did. :) See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sizeof() for compile-time sized arrays.

```
const char *names[] = { "Bob", "Adam", "Simon" };
std::for_each(names, names + sizeof(names)/sizeof(*names), [](const char* arg) {
    std::cout << arg << "\n";
});
std::cin.get();
```

For dynamically sized arrays, you should be using `std::vector<std::string>` and iterate over that.

Excuse my use of lambdas, your compiler (probably) doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0):

add them to a container instead, and iterate over them using for_each

 i use a vector for my example:

```
void function(string name)
{
    cout << name;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> nameVector;

    nameVector.push_back("Bob");
    nameVector.push_back("Adam");
    nameVector.push_back("Simon");

    for_each(nameVector.begin(), nameVector.end(), function);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not replace the argument passed to func with a reference to a pointer to const char, in order to achieve what you want.  Kind of like this:

```
const char *names[] = { "Bob", "Adam", "Simon" };

void func( const char* &arg )
{
   cout << arg << endl;
}

int main()
{
    for_each( names, 
              names + sizeof( names ) / sizeof( names[ 0 ] ), 
              func );
}
```

And obviously for a NULL-terminated string array, just subtract 1 from the array size...

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T>
struct NullTerminatedIterator {
  typedef NullTerminatedIterator<T> NTI;
  T * current;
  NTI & operator++() {current++; return this;}
  T & operator*() {return *current;} 
  NullTerminatedIterator(T * start): current(start) {}
  static NTI end() {return  NTI(0);}
  bool operator==(const NTI & that) {return current==that.current;}

}
```

Comment: I think this is what I want, but I can't quite get it to work in practice. What would the for_each line look like using this iterator?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not for_each, but I wanted to use old regular for-loop to do the same. This one is from the [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx):

> This reinterpretation of a double-null-terminated string as really a list of strings with an empty string as the terminator makes writing code to walk through a double-null-terminated string quite straightforward:

```
for (LPTSTR pszz = pszzStart; *pszz; pszz += lstrlen(pszz) + 1) {
   // ... do something with pszz ...
}
```

Looks kinda clean to me!

Answer (score 0):

```
    // C version 
    const char* vars[16]={"$USER","$HOME","$DISPLAY","$PASSWORD",0};

    for(const char** pc = vars; *pc!=0; pc++)
    {
            printf("%s",*pc);
    }
```