# Can/Should I inherit from an STL iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Can/Should i inherit from STL iterator to implement my own iterator class? If no, why not?

Comment: Do you mean from any STL iterator, or specifically from the `std::iterator` type?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/839958/14065

Comment: You might also want to read the currently lowest-sorted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22211034/1269892

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### Short answer

Many consider that the class `std::iterator` does not offer much compared to regular type aliases, and even obfuscates them a bit by not explicitly providing the names and relying on the order of the template parameters instead. It is deprecated in C++17 and is likely to be gone in a few years.

This means that you shouldn't use `std::iterator` anymore. You can read the whole post below if you're interested in the full story (there's a bit of redundancy since it has been started before the deprecation proposal).

---

#### Legacy answer

*You can ignore everything below if you're not interested in history. The following fragments even contradict themselves several times.*

As of today (C++11/C++14), the standard seems to imply that it isn't a good idea anymore to inherit from `std::iterator` to implement custom iterators. Here is a brief explanation, from [N3931](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3931.html#52):

> Although the Standard has made this mistake almost a dozen times, I recommend not depicting `directory_iterator` and `recursive_directory_iterator` as deriving from `std::iterator`, since that's a binding requirement on implementations. Instead they should be depicted as having the appropriate typedefs, and leave it up to implementers to decide how to provide them. (The difference is observable to users with `is_base_of`, not that they should be asking that question.)
>
> *[2014-02-08 Daniel comments and provides wording]*
>
> This issue is basically similar to the kind of solution that had been used to remove the requirement to derive from `unary_function` and friends as described by [N3198](https://wg21.link/N3198) and I'm strongly in favour to follow that spirit here as well. I'd like to add that basically all "newer" iterator types (such as the `regex` related iterator) don't derive from `std::iterator` either.

The paper cites [N3198](https://wg21.link/N3198) which itself states that it follows the deprecation discussed in [N3145](https://wg21.link/N3145). The reasons for deprecating the classes that only exist to provide `typedef`s are given as such:

> Our experience with concepts gives us confidence that it is rarely necessary to depend on specific base class-derived class relations, if availability of types and functions is sufficient. The new language tools allow us even in the absence of language-supported concepts to deduce the existence of typenames in class types, which would introduce a much weaker coupling among them. Another advantage of replacing inheritance by associated types is the fact, that this will reduce the number of cases, where ambiguities arise: This can easily happen, if a type would inherit both from `unary_function` and `binary_function` (This makes sense, if a functor is both an unary and a binary function object).

**tl;dr**: classes which only provide `typedef`s are now deemed useless. Moreover, they increase coupling when it is not needed, are more verbose, and can have unwanted side effects in some corner cases (see the previous quotation).

---

**Update:** [issue 2438 from N4245](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4245.html#2438) seems to actually contradict what I asserted earlier:

> For LWG convenience, nine STL iterators are depicted as deriving from `std::iterator` to get their `iterator_category`/etc. typedefs. Unfortunately (and unintentionally), this also mandates the inheritance, which is observable (not just through `is_base_of`, but also overload resolution). This is unfortunate because it confuses users, who can be misled into thinking that their own iterators must derive from `std::iterator`, or that overloading functions to take `std::iterator` is somehow meaningful. This is also unintentional because the STL's most important iterators, the container iterators, aren't required to derive from `std::iterator`. (Some are even allowed to be raw pointers.) Finally, this unnecessarily constrains implementers, who may not want to derive from `std::iterator`. (For example, to simplify debugger views.)

To sum up, I was wrong, @aschepler was right: it *can* be used, but it is certainely not required - it isn't discouraged either. The whole "let's remove `std::iterator`" thing exists for the standard not to constrain the standard library implementers.

---

**Round 3:** [P0174R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0.html#2.1) proposes to deprecate `std::iterator` for a possible removal in the future. The proposal is already pretty good at explaining why it should be deprecated, so here we go:

> The long sequence of void arguments is much less clear to the reader than simply providing the expected typedefs in the class definition itself, which is the approach taken by the current working draft, following the pattern set in C++14 where we deprecated the derivation throughout the library of functors from unary_function and binary_function.
>
> In addition to the reduced clarity, the iterator template also lays a trap for the unwary, as in typical usage it will be a dependent base class, which means it will not be looking into during name lookup from within the class or its member functions. This leads to surprised users trying to understand why the following simple usage does not work:
>
> ```
> #include <iterator>
>
> template <typename T>
> struct MyIterator : std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> {
>    value_type data;  // Error: value_type is not found by name lookup 
>
>    // ... implementations details elided ...
> };
> ```
>
> The reason of clarity alone was sufficient to persuade the LWG to update the standard library specification to no longer mandate the standard iterator adapators as deriving from std::iterator, so there is no further use of this template within the standard itself. Therefore, it looks like a strong candidate for deprecation.

This is becoming a bit tiring and not everyone seems to agree, so I will let you draw your own conclusions. If the committee eventually decides that `std::iterator` should be deprecated, then it will make it pretty clear that you shouldn't use it anymore. Note that the [follow-up paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r1.html#2.1) highlights a great support for the removal of `std::iterator`:

> **Update from Jacksonville, 2016:**
>
> **Poll:** Deprecate `iterator` for C++17?? 
>   **SF  F   N   A   SA** 
>   6    10  1    0   0

In the above poll results, *SF*, *F*, *N*, *A* and *SA* stand for *Strongly For*, *For*, *Neutral*, *Against* and *Strongly Against*.

> **Update from Oulu, 2016:**
>
> **Poll:** Still want to deprecate `std::iterator?` 
>   **SF  F   N   A   SA** 
>   3   6  3  2  0

[P0619R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0619r1.html#3.13) proposes to remove `std::iterator`, possibly as soon as C++20, and also proposes to enhance `std::iterator_traits` so that it can automatically deduce the types `difference_type`, `pointer` and `reference` the way `std::iterator` does when they're not explicitly provided.

Comment: I don't read any of this as recommending that user-defined classes should not inherit `std::iterator`.  The point of N3931 is that the Standard library spec should not require *library classes* to inherit it.  In the case of `unary_function` and `binary_function`, that whole model was determined inferior to SFINAE methods, `std::bind`, etc., types, functions, and all.  When you mean to write an iterator class, you haven't really done so until you define all the correct typedefs and support the correct expressions.  `std::iterator` is just one way to make part of that job easier.

Comment: @Morwenn Could you perhaps update with a new TLDR? I'm getting that I should establish my typedefs internally and no longer depend upon an iterator tag or inherit from `iterator` because it will be deprecated in C++17. Is that correct?

Comment: @Morwenn Thanks! I have asked a follow up question and felt it was important to link it to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37031805/2642059

Answer (score 10):

If you mean `std::iterator`: yes, that's what it's for.

If you mean anything else: no, because none of the STL iterators have `virtual` destructors. They're not meant for inheritance and a class inheriting from them might not clean up properly.

Comment: Iterators are not used in a context were that matters (ie you never have a base cass pointer pointing at the derived iterator). Iterators are always objects.

Comment: This advice is overly broad. It's OK not to have a virtual destructor if the derived class doesn't need any cleanup (automatically generated or otherwise), or if it won't be used polymorphically. It's extremely rare to have a pointer to an iterator.

Comment: @Martin: it's still *possible* to obtain a pointer to an iterator, and in that case, you're screwed. I've used pointers to (heavy-duty, not STL) iterators in a project.

Comment: You are aware, that `std::iterator` doesn't have a virtual destructor either? @MarkRansom: Deleting a class with a non-virtual destructor via a pointer to base class is always UB.

Comment: @MikeMB You're probably right, but my larger point stands: iterators are extremely unlikely to be deleted polymorphically. Even the functions that work with them are probably template based to work with the fully derived class.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I agree. I just wanted to point out that little flaw in your statement, because until recently I wasn't aware of that problem either.

Answer (score 6):

No one should not because of the potential problems that might be encountered. Probably you are better off using ***Composition*** rather than ***Inheritance*** with STL Iterators.

***Undefined Behavior due to absence of virtual destructors:***
STL containers & iterators are not meant to act as base classes as they do not have virtual destructors.

For classes with no virtual destructors being used as Base class, the problem arises when deallocating through a pointer to the base class (delete, delete[] etc). Since the classes don't have virtual destructors, they cannot be cleaned up properly and results in Undefined Behavior.

One might argue that there would not be a need to delete the iterator polymorphically & hence nothing wrong to go ahead with deriving from STL iterators, well there might be some other problems like:

***Inheritance maynot be possible at all:***
All iterator types in the standard container are ***Implementation defined***.
For e.g: `std::vector<T>::iterator` might be just a `T*`. In this case, you simply cannot inherit from it.

The C++ standard has no provisions demanding that say `std::vector<T>::iterator` does not
use inheritance inhibiting techniques to prevent derivation. Thus, if you are deriving from a STL iterator you are relying on a feature of your STL that happens to allow derivation. That makes such an implementation ***non portable***.

***Buggy behaviors if not implemented properly:***
Consider that you are deriving from vector iterator class like:

```
class yourIterator : std::vector<T>::iterator { ... };
```

There might be a function which operates on the vector iterators,
For ex:

```
void doSomething(std::vector<T>::iterator to, std::vector<T>::iterator from);
```

Since `yourIterator` is a `std::vector<T>::iterator` you can call `doSomething()` on your container class but you will be facing the ugly problem of `Object Slicing`. The `doSomething()` has to be implemented in a proper templated manner, to avoid the
problem.

***Problems while using Standard Library Algorithms:***
Consider you are using the derivation from vector iterator, and then you use a Standard library algorithm like `std::transform()`

For Ex:

```
yourIterator a;
yourIterator b;
...
std::transform( a++, b--, ... );
```

The postfix `operator ++` returns a  `std::vector<T>::iterator` and not a
`yourIterator` resulting in a wrong template being chosen.

Thus, Inheriting from STL Iterators is possible indeed but if you ready to dig out all such and many other potential problems and address them, Personally I won't give it the time and the effort to do so.

Comment: You mean, classes with virtual destructor can only be derived from?

Comment: @Nawaz: You mean "You mean, only classes with virutal destructor can be derived from?"? :D

Comment: Hope that answers your query or sarcasm, whatever it was.

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about `std::iterator` template, then yes, you should, but I hope you do understand that it has no functionality, just a bunch of typedefs. The pro of this decision is that your iterator can be fed to `iterator_traits` template.

If, on the other hand, you're talking about some specific STL iterator, like `vector<T>::iterator` or other, then the answer is a resounding ***NO***. Let alone everything else, you don't know for sure that it's actually a class (e.g. the same `vector<T>::iterator` can be just typedefed as `T*`)