# How to write standard C++ iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I have the following simple `Graph` class, where for each `Node`, I store a set of outgoing `Arcs`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>

struct Arc {
  char label;
  int targetNode;
};

struct Graph {
  std::vector<int> nodes;
  std::map< int, std::set<Arc*> > outgoingArcsPerNode;
};
```

How can I provide a standard C++ `iterator` over all the arcs in the graph (order of iteration doesn't matter) that hides how the arcs are stored in the graph?

I would like to use it similar to the following:

```
int main() {
  Graph g;
  for (Graph::const_iterator it = g.arcsBegin(); it != g.arcsEnd(); ++it) {
    Arc* a = *it;
  }
}
```

I heard of `boost::iterator`, but I find it confusing. Maybe someone could give a hint how to use it in this case?

Comment: Perhaps just do `typedef const_iterator std::map<...>` inside `Graph` and then define the functions (ie `arcsBegin()` and `arcsEnd()`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Iterator in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839958/custom-iterator-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use boost, have a look at what iterators must provide : [STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/InputIterator.html).

Otherwise, you may use [boost iterator library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html). See the [iterator_facade tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#tutorial-example) which is very close to what you're asking.

Comment: In addition to this, I found that reading the STL source was helpful (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html). Specifically, I used the documentation referenced above to find an iterator that was similar to the data structure that I'm writing it for (eg. my data structure's iterator requirements were close to that of an stl::list, so I used the docs referenced above in this answer to see what iterator type an stl::list used). Then, I read the std::list::iterator source from the link that I just included. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create class which has two iterators inside: one over map and another over set.

Each ++ is applied to set iterator. When it reaches the end, increment map iterator and reinitialize set iterator.

Also you can use boost::iterator_facade - it will not help to implement algorithm of the iteration, but will minimize your effort on making your iterator compatible to STL expectations...