# deque::insert() at index?

Tags: c++, deque

How do I `insert()` a bunch of items to the middle of a `deque` in linear time?

(The items I am inserting are **not** accessible through an STL-style iterator.)

Comment: 'Mydeque.insert(mydeque.begin()+15, obj);'

Comment: How are the items you want to insert accessible? Are they in an array, or some other library's (beside stl) container class?

Comment: @ScottLangham: They're coming from a generator-like object, so I have no idea when I've reached the end until I do. (I *guess* I could make an STL-style wrapper for it by doing all the test in `operator ==` with `end()`, but it'd be a little uglier of a solution than I'm hoping for.)

Comment: You can make an `istream` subclass and then pass it to `istream_iterator` which provides an end iterator which is using the default constructor: `istream_iterator(stream)` is the `begin` and `istream_iterator()` is the `end`.

Comment: @Dani `istream` is specifically designed to read and interpret characters. "Adapting" it to the current problem would mean to overwrite `istream::fail` and defining `operator<<(istream, myElement)` in an inconsistent way, which is a lot uglier imo than defining a specific iterator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `deque::insert(iterator pos, const T&x)` function taking the position `pos` as `deque::iterator` and a single element. Using this method you could insert all elements  one by one. `pos` can easily be obtained (if you have an index before which you want to insert the element) by `deque.begin()+index`. The `insert` method returns an iterator for the newly inserted element, simply increment this returned iterator to get the next position:

```
deque::iterator it = myDeque.begin()+index;
while(n--) {
  it = myDeque.insert(it, currentElement);
  it++;
  currentElement = ... // However you get your next element ...
}
```

This however cantake `O(n*k)` time, since insertion of a single element is (iirc) a linear time operation iirc.

The second overload is `deque::insert(iterator pos, InputIterator f, InputIterator l)`: Remember that simple pointers also fulfill the requirements of an STL input iterator, so if you have a C-Style array `T array[]` of length `n` containing your elements, you could insert all elements from this array with

```
d.insert(pos, array, array+n);
```

This operation can be carried out in linear time, i.e. `O(n+k)`. I'm not sure if this is guaranteed by the standard, but I suppose that most implementation will do it efficiently.

**EDIT**

I quickly checked with Microsoft's implementation, they do it by a sequence of either `push_back` or `push_front`, whatever is closer to `pos` and then rotating the elements to their final place, which guarantees the above `O(n+k)` complexity. Of course, that could also be done "by hand" like:

```
size_type _Off = pos - d.begin();
size_type _Oldsize = d.size();
if (_Off <= d.size() / 2)
{   // closer to front, push to front then rotate
  while (hasMoreElements())
    push_front(nextElement()); // prepend flipped

  size_type _Num = d.size() - _Oldsize;
  std::reverse(d.begin(), d.begin() + _Num); // flip new stuff in place
  std::rotate(d.begin(), d.begin() + _Num, begin() + _Num + _Off);
}
else
{ // closer to back
  while (hasMoreElements())
    push_front(nextElement()); // prepend flipped

  std::rotate(begin() + _Off, begin() + _Oldsize, end());
}
```

(I copied the code from Microsofts implementation of `deque::insert`, removing debug code and exception handling,

Comment: Are you sure the iterator doesn't get invalidated?

Comment: You mean in the first case? Yes, `deque::insert` returns a valid iterator and incrementing doesn't invalidate it. All other iterators are invalid though after insertion (as is `pos` after insertion in the second case)

Comment: Ahhh my bad, I didn't notice you said `it = ...`. :) +1

Comment: Doesn't this use linear time for Each element? Meaning inserting a bunch of elements will take n*m time...

Comment: As I tried to explain: If you insert each element one by one (thus using `deque::insert(pos, element)`), yes: This is the first case and I noted the complexity `O(n*k)`. If you insert them all together, no: `deque::insert(pos, start end)` can be accomplished in linear time (`O(n+k)`) by adding the elements at the end (`push_back` resp. `push_front` is amortized `O(1)`) and "rotating" them into place (taking `O(n)` for the whole rotate step). Thus `k*O(1)+O(n)=O(n+k)` ...

Answer (score 1):

Call the insert method that takes a sequence of items to insert, see the 3rd method listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcww84w5(v=vs.71).aspx

And, create your own STL-style iterator to access the items you want to insert. See:

[Custom Iterator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839958/custom-iterator-in-c)

Comment: I guess this is the best method in terms of performance, though I was hoping for a solution without making my own wrapper. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

**Input:**

Deque: lengtl = l,

New items (m = number of new items)

**Algo:**

create a new deque (1)

Copy all items from original deque until where you want to insert the new ones (p)

Add new items (m)

Add items from old deque (m-p)

Maybe you can just use the new deque but at worst:

Copy new deque onto old one (after a complete clear: ):

Cost (l+m)

The worst cost is thus: origsize * 2 + newitems which is linear.

The "clear deck" isn't counted here but it is also linear ( at worst).

Comment: That has of course also `O(n)` memory consumption whereas the other solutions require only constant memory ...

Answer (score 0):

Add all the elements after the insertion point to a vector.
Remove all elements after insertion point.
Append new range to deque.
Append vector to deque.

This is O(2n) worst case, instead of O(n^2).

Comment: That has of course also `O(n)` memory consumption whereas the other solutions require only constant memory ...