# Strided iterator incompatible with stl::sort

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I've copied some code from a C++ cookbook to implement a strided iterator.  The iterator seems to work with other `stl` functions like `copy`, but won't work with `sort`.  My guess is that it has something to do with there being some operators missing. Here's my header file for the strided iterator (From the Oreilly C++ cookbook)

```
#define STRIDEITER_HPP

#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>

template<class Iter_T>
class stride_iter
{
public:
  // public typedefs
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter_T>::value_type value_type;
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter_T>::reference reference;
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter_T>::difference_type difference_type;
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter_T>::pointer pointer;
  typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
  typedef stride_iter self;

  // constructors
  stride_iter( ) : m(NULL), step(0) { };
  stride_iter(const self& x) : m(x.m), step(x.step) { }
  stride_iter(Iter_T x, difference_type n) : m(x), step(n) { }

  // operators
  self& operator++( ) { m += step; return *this; }
  self operator++(int) { self tmp = *this; m += step; return tmp; }
  self& operator+=(const difference_type x) { m += (x * step); return *this; }
  self& operator--( ) { m -= step; return *this; }
  self operator--(int) { self tmp = *this; m -= step; return tmp; }
  self& operator-=(const difference_type x) { m -= x * step; return *this; }
  reference operator[](const difference_type n) { return m[n * step]; }
  reference operator*( ) { return *m; }

  // friend operators
  friend bool operator==(const self& x, const self& y) {
    assert(x.step == y.step);
    return x.m == y.m;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(const self& x, const self& y) {
    assert(x.step == y.step);
    return x.m != y.m;
  }
  friend bool operator<(const self& x, const self& y) {
    assert(x.step == y.step);
    return x.m < y.m;
  }
  friend difference_type operator-(const self& x, const self& y) {
    assert(x.step == y.step);
    return (x.m - y.m) / x.step;
  }

  friend self operator+(const self& x, difference_type y) {
    assert(x.step == y.step);
    return x += (y * x.step);
  }
  friend self operator+(difference_type x, const self& y) {
    assert(x.step == y.step);
    return y += x * x.step;
  }
private:
  Iter_T m;
  difference_type step;
};
#endif
```

I call is using

```
#include "strideiter.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( ) {

  int *a;
  a =(int*) malloc(10*sizeof(int));

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      a[i]=10-i;
    }

  int skip=2;

  stride_iter<int*> first(a+2, skip);
  stride_iter<int*> last(a + 2+8, skip);
  sort(first,last);
}
```

I get several errors, the first one is:

```
strideiter.hpp(52): error: expression must have class type
  assert(x.step == y.step);
```

Do I need multiple implementations for `+=`?

Comment: `y` is of type `difference_type`, which can be/is an integer like `int` or `long` and therefore has no members (`y.step`).

Comment: `a =(int*) malloc(10*sizeof(int));` Why don't you use the C++ tools? `std::array<int, 10> a;`, `std::vector<int> a(10);` or even `int *a = new int[10];`, although `std::unique_ptr<int[]> a{new int[10]};` would be slightly better.

Comment: Because `malloc` is really `mkl_malloc` for aligned memory, and it's going to be used for some very large matrix multiplication operations that only work on plain old arrays.

Comment: Ok, that sounds much more reasonable than plain `malloc`, even though I'd still recommend using smart pointers (e.g. a `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter).

Comment: As James Kanze pointed out (or alluded to) you already have undefined behaviour here: `a + 2+8`. As you're already working with the non-C++-standard `mkl_malloc`, make sure your implementation behaves "as expected".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixing `operator+` and providing an `operator-(self, difference_type)` and it compiles fine. The `RandomAccessIterator` "concept" and `std::sort` have a vast amount of requirements, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16905832/420683) in another question involving iterators.

```
friend self operator+(const self& x, difference_type y) {
  // do not modify `x`, but return a modified copy
  return self(x.m + (y * x.step), x.step);
  // idiomatically:
  // self temp(x);
  // temp += y;
  // return temp;
}
friend self operator+(difference_type x, const self& y) {
  return y+x;
}

friend self operator-(const self& x, difference_type y) {
  return self(x.m - (y * x.step), x.step);
}
```

---

For this usage:

```
int main( ) {

  int a[10];
  //a =(int*) malloc(10*sizeof(int));

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      a[i]=10-i;
    }

  for(int e : a) std::cout << e << ", ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  int skip=2;

  stride_iter<int*> first(a+2, skip);
  stride_iter<int*> last(a + 2+8, skip);
  sort(first,last);

  for(int e : a) std::cout << e << ", ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 
10, 9, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 8, 1,
```

Which seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you downvote so I can improve my answer.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're declaring the iterator to be
a `random_access_iterator`, but you're not providing the
`operator+` and `operator-` functions.

Having said that, your iterator is playing with fire, since it
will only work if the size of the container is an exact multiple
of the stride.  If you have a container with, say, 100 elements,
and you ask for a stride of 3, you'll have undefined behavior.
To be useful, your iterator will have to pick up both the start
and end of the range, so that it can avoid striding over the end
(or the beginning, when striding backwards).

Comment: "Having said that, your iterator is playing with fire, since it will only work if the size of the container is an exact multiple of the stride" I thought the same, but the burden isn't entirely on the iterator. As shown in the example, the creator of the iterator can also check if the iterator can be safely used for a purpose (read: the end iterator). A past-the-end iterator isn't always possible, though, I agree.

Comment: @DyP The problem is that the constraint `size % stride == 0` isn't reasonable.  So when you're advancing, you have to check whether you can advance or not, and if not, advance as far as you can (which will put you one past the end).

Comment: What I was referring to is that the size of the *range* implicitly defined via begin and end iterator (and not the size of the container) is required to have `size%stride==0`. This requirement has to/can be checked by the creator of the range, but cannot be reasonably be checked by the iterator itself (e.g. offsets). A range library might be better suited for striding iterators.

Comment: @DyP I understood what you meant, but... it makes it impossible to visit the last element that should be visited in a container, because the end iterator for the range would be beyond the end of the container.

Comment: I agree, at least not w/o UB. The OP is already using a non-standard allocation function (`mkl_malloc`, see comments), so possibly the behaviour is well-defined for the implementation. Without relying on UB/implementation-defined behaviour, the iterator necessarily gets bigger and more complex.