# Sorting not std::vector of custom objects

Tags: c++

On [Sorting a vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects)
I see how to sort std::vector.

How to sort a custom Vector?

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

template<typename T>
class Iterator
{
    using ValueType = T::ValueType;
public:
    Iterator(ValueType* ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}

    ValueType& operator*()
    {
        return *m_ptr;
    }

    Iterator& operator--()
    {
        m_ptr--;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        m_ptr++;
        return *this;
    }

    // Iterator& operator++(int)
    // {
    //     auto ptr = m_ptr;
    //     m_ptr++;
    //     return *this;
    // }

    bool operator==(const Iterator& other) const
    {
        return m_ptr == other.m_ptr;
    }


    bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    bool operator<(const Iterator& other) const
    {
        return *m_ptr < *other.m_ptr;
    }

private:
    ValueType* m_ptr;
};

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
    using ValueType = T;
    void allocate(size_t capacity)
    {
        capacity += m_capacity;

        T* data = new T[capacity];
        std::copy_n(m_data, m_capacity, data);

        m_capacity = capacity;

        delete[] m_data;
        m_data = data;
    }

    void push_back(T value)
    {
        if (!(m_index < m_capacity))
            allocate(3);

        m_data[m_index++] = value;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index) { return m_data[index]; }

    size_t size() { return m_index; }

    size_t capacity() { return m_capacity; }

    Iterator<Vector<T>> begin()
    {
        return Iterator<Vector<T>>(m_data);
    }

    Iterator<Vector<T>> end()
    {
        return Iterator<Vector<T>>(m_data + m_index);
    }

private:
    size_t m_index = 0;
    size_t m_capacity = 0;
    T* m_data = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "starting... " << endl;

    int A[] = {2,7,9,1,7};

    Vector<int> V;
    
    cout << "size of A " << std::size(A) << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(A); ++i)
        V.push_back(A[i]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < V.size(); ++i)
    cout << V[i] << endl;

    cout << "V capacity is " << V.capacity() << endl;

    Iterator<Vector<int>>beg = V.begin();
    Iterator<Vector<int>>end = V.end();

    cout << "beg is " << *beg << endl;
    cout << "end is " << *--end << endl;

    // for (Iterator<Vector<int>> it = V.begin(); it != V.end(); ++it)
    for (const auto& v : V)
        cout << v << endl;

    if (beg < end)
        cout << "<" << endl;



    // sort a vector of custom Data type
    struct Data
    {
        bool operator<(const Data& other) const
        {
            return false;
        }
    };

    Vector<Data> x; // does not work, why?
    // std::vector<Data> x; // works
    std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());

}
```

I got the following error, but is too cryptic for me to understand

```
In file included from /Projecs/dynamicarray/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/mutex:192:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:20:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/system_error:154:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:576:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:1025:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:1771:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/nth_element.h:15:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/sort.h:712:86: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::iterator_traits<Iterator<Vector<Data>>>'
  std::sort(__first, __last, __less<typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type>());
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/Projecs/dynamicarray/main.cpp:147:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::sort<Iterator<Vector<Data>>>' requested here
    std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
```

Comment: The simplest path is probably writing your iterator to be compatible with `std::sort`.

Comment: A standard iterator not only has to define all the methods, it also has to define some types.  One of those is `value_type`.

Comment: The most immediate error to sort out is: `error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::iterator_traits<Iterator<Vector<Data>>>'`

Comment: You might want to use raw pointers as iterators for your `Vector` without wrapping them into a special type.

Comment: Why are you implementing a custom `vector` in the first place?

Comment: How to create a cutom iterator. https://stackoverflow.com/q/839958/14065

Answer (score 2):

The standard algorithms depend on the iterator being defined in a certain way. For example, the iterator is expected to have `value_type` defined to be the type of the element the iterator references.

If you define your iterator to meet all the requirements of a [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), it should work with `std::sort`.

If your definition is different, you can specialize [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) for your custom iterator type.

If you use raw pointers as your iterators, there's already a specialization to handle it.

Comment: Don't we need a LegacyRandomAccessIterator for std::sort? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: @KcFnMi:  Yes.  Nice catch.  I've corrected the answer.